# How to prove (analytically) that $\sin(\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{2}))=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$?

Tags: trigonometry, angle

I calculated $\sin(\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{2}))$ using [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sen%28tg%5E%7B-1%7D%28%5Csqrt%282%29%29) and got it as a result $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$. However, I was unable to find an identity to obtain this result.

Is there any way to calculate this value without using Wolfram?

Comment: What do you consider "analytical" and what are you willing to take for granted?

Comment: For any x, $$\sin(\tan^{-1}(x))=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $t=\tan^{-1} \sqrt2$. Then, $ \tan t=\sqrt2$ and
$$\sin t = \tan t\cos t= \frac {\tan t}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2t}}=\sqrt{\frac23}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\arctan x$ is an angle whose tangent function is $\frac{x}{1}$. Considering the sides of the right triangle. We have apposite side is $x$, adjacent side is $1$ and hypothenuse is $\sqrt{1+x^2}$. Therefore the sine of this angle is:

$$\frac{\text{opposite side}}{\text{hypotenuse}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\tag1$$

So, we have:

$$\sin\left(\arctan\left(x\right)\right)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\tag2$$

In your case:

$$\sin\left(\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}\right)\right)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\tag3$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use the mid-school formula:
$$\sin^2\theta=\frac{\tan^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}$$
and use that $\sin\theta$ and $\tan\theta$ have the same sign on $\bigl(-\frac\pi 2,\frac\pi 2\bigr)$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Also, the angle $t$ of right triangle satisfies

$$\sin^2 t= \dfrac{2}{3}$$
$$\cos^2 t= \dfrac{1}{3}$$
$$\tan^2 t= 2 $$